Flutter pubspec.yaml dependency selection algorithm
in my flutter project I have injectable_generator: ^2.4.1 in the pubspec.yaml file, while the latest version on the pub dev is currently injectable_generator: ^2.6.1, and the question is, by what mechanism does flutter select the dependencies that will eventually be installed generated in pubspec.lock because it ends up with the injectable_generator version:
dependency: "direct dev"
description:
name: injectable_generator
sha256: ac28d612899beda76a6375cb42dc6655a8c3ce3606cc53c25649e3c101d5d41a
url: "https://pub.dev"
source: hosted
version: "2.5.1"
Here's the answer please, how does flutter do this, looks at the pubspec, then where does it go, to the pub.dev? and does pubspec.lock already generate the required version? then the main question is why and how did he decide to take not the latest version 2.6.1, but took 2.5.1, what algorithm is he guided by, what does he look at?my Pubspec.yaml[versions of libraryPubspec.lock](https://i.sstatic.net/oTZVJHyA.png)
I would like to know the detailed algorithm for how flutter selects the final dependency in a library project

Rather old, but fun... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fifni75xYeQ&list=PLOU2XLYxmsIIJr3vjxggY7yGcGO7i9BK5&index=17

You could force the version to 2.6.1 (in your pubspec.yaml), run pub get and then see if reports a conflict

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It takes the highest version available that satisfies the constraint unless it already has loaded a lower version in the pub cache before.
Most likely the first time you did a flutter pub get or ran any flutter project with that dependency 2.5.1 was the highest.
It's typically saved at
C:\Users\<usernanme>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\

If you were to go to that location and delete everything there. And after that do a flutter pub get chances are it actually would take the 2.6.1 version.
Personally I like to therefore put exact versions in my pubspec.yaml and not use the ^ symbol because of running into issues before that the same project used different dependencies on different machines because of the way it works.
^2.4.1 really means >=2.4.1 <3.0.0
if you want exactly version 2.4.1 just leave out the ^
